# Can my husband apply for a Schengen visa from the UK?

Tags: schengen

I have been in UK for three months on work permit visa. My husband will be traveling to UK now as my dependent. Can he apply for a Schengen visa from the UK, since I am staying here & he is my dependent, although he won't have been in UK for 3 months?

Comment: How long is his UK visa issued for?

Comment: Its issued till March 2018.

Comment: Dependent visa issued for > 6 months should be fine

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm- so its not mandatory for a person to stay more than 3months in UK prior applying schengen visa from UK?

Comment: That rule is a member stipulation and not a Schengen one, so it really depends upon which country you are thinking of.

Comment: Am thinking of France & Amsterdam

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what kind of visa your husband has. From [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html):

> Applicant must at least meet the following criteria in order to be eligible to submit a Schengen visa application:
>
> - holding a valid passport/travel document
> - **holding a valid UK residence permit**. In case applicant holds a short stay visa, a C type visa (see example here), for the UK, then applicant needs to apply for a Schengen visa from his/her residence country.

So if your husband has a residency permit he is free to make an application.